# Is there a maximum number of clicktag variables allowed in a banner ad?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So, this is pretty silly. I'm working on a banner ad that utilizes the clicktag. It's a surprisingly fancy one that uses pointroll, and when you hover over the 300x250 banner ad, it pulls up a larger one overtop of it that is bigger and much more interactive. In total, the larger banner has 29 clicktags, all using the variables "clickTag1" to "clickTag29".

The banners are all done, everything fires correctly (according to my trace statements). However, I'm in the middle of QA, testing all of the clicktags using this validator: https://flashval-temp.appspot.com/validator/ , when suddenly, it stops working after clickTag20. I thought it may have been the validator at first, so I tried other validators. No luck. I went back into my code (everything is a duplicate of one template, so the only code changes made were the changes to the string), and made sure to test it again. They're firing off just fine according to my trace statements.

Finally, and this doesn't seem to make sense to me, but I switched the variables clickTag20 and clickTag21. The button that fired off clickTag20 worked, so I assigned it clickTag21. The button that was assigned clickTag21 was the first to stop working, so I assigned it clickTag20. When I ran that through the validator, the button that was assigned to clickTag20, regardless of which button it was, worked! The one that was assigned clickTag21 never did, also regardless of which button it was fired off from.

The variable is a string of a paramObj. How does the content of that string matter? I would have assumed it was compile order, but even in that case, clickTag21 should have fired and not clickTag20. What is going on here? Has anyone else experienced this? If so, did you have a workaround? Please and thank you!!

Comment: By "no luck" with other validators, I mean that I haven't found one that works as well as the one I'm using. The other ones either "can't detect" my clickTag, doesn't provide enough feedback that the clickTag worked, or doesn't seem to think my clickTag works at all. Most of the reason is because my client uses a custom clickTag rather than the standard "clickTAG" string. Of course the code doesn't say "clickTAG" anywhere, as it is "clickTag#" or "clickTag##".

Comment: So I'm starting to think that this particular validator can't detect more than 20 different clickTags. But that still doesn't explain when I use it, I click clickTag20 first, and then clickTag21 second (as opposed to clicking them all in numerical order), and clickTag21 still doesn't work, even it is only my second click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the thing... when you set a clicktag you're waiting for a flashvar. A parameter sent from the HTML to your SWF file. (more: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)

Usually you'd test, if this parameter doesn't exists, the banner should do nothing, otherwise, open the link.

Turns out, and this is a guess, that these validators don't know how many clicktags you have in your flash file - or how many parameters you're waiting for - , so they pass up to 20 variables to your flash file, which is more than reasonable.

The bottom line is: if your events are working, you should be fine. Pointroll has a QA team, if something comes up, they will let you know, but as far as I can see from here, you should be fine.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I feel confident that they'll work. With your response, I can explain this to my project manager when she asks me why I don't have all the QA files.